# Uniqueness of users with devise and acts_as_tenant in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, multi-tenant

I am using the [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/) gem to manage multi-tenancy, and I'm using devise to manage users.

I have only setup devise User model and Account model for tenants.
I can create users against multiple tenants - this is all working fine EXCEPT when I attempt to create two users with the same email against different tenant ID's I get a uniqeness error.
I am using the validates_uniqueness_to_tenant option as described.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  acts_as_tenant(:account)
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :email
end
```

Account model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:account, :subdomain)
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

This looks like it should be working based on all documentation in acts_as_tenant, do I need to override something at the devise level instead?

EDIT: After some head-scratching and a bit of a break, the problem is I believe because by default Devise has added a unique index to the Email column.
This obviously does not gel with what acts_as_tenant wants to do...
I will try removing the index and see whether Devise pukes or not.

EDIT 2: OK, have officially given up on this for now. I have hand-rolled authentication for the main site and this is working properly with acts_as_tenant.
I can only assume some incompatibility between acts_as_tenant and Devise at some layer - beyond me to find it at this stage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to do this is by removing the validatable module from devise and run your own validations like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant :account
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me

  #remove :validatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  #run own validations
  #I've omitted any emailformatting checks for clarity's sake.
  validates :email, 
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { scope: :account_id, case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password,
    presence: true,
    length: { :in => 6..20 },
    :if => :password_required?

protected
  # copied from validatable module
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: Good answer - worth noting for anyone else t remember to remove the unique index on email that devise adds as well.

Comment: FYI: AaT provides a scoped validator: `validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :email`. Also the email format can easily be done using `validates_format_of :email, with: Devise.email_regexp`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I wonder if changing the order might help acts_as_tenant do its thing before devise takes over.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_tenant(:account)
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :email

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

Comment: Sounds like you are on to something with the devise index. If it's any help, in my systems I allow users to bind to more than one tenant and then give them the ability to switch their current tenant. This may not work for your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question. Sweam's solution is pretty good.

But I prefer to not override the default behaviour. So I came up with this solution:

```
validate :remove_old_email_validation_error
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?, :scope => [:account_id]

private

def remove_old_email_validation_error
  errors.delete(:email)
end
```

We remove the default validation error for email, therefore ignoring the validation check, and we do our own validation again.
What I have added is from the Validatable module, but i have added `:scope` to it.

Its important to keep the order. Add the above code after the `devise` command.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it as:

`validate :remove_old_uniquess_email_error`

```
private

  def remove_old_uniquess_email_error
   errors.delete(:email) if self.company_id.nil? && errors[:email].present? && errors[:email] == ["already taken"]
  end
```